# I want to get all the filenames into a variable in a particular path

Tags: bash, shell

I want to get all the filename into a variable in a path so that I could list all the files inside it no matter what type they are.

As of now If there is a directory inside the file or a folder then its name should be displayed not its content

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Hello World
for file in /C:/Users/shubham.tomar/Desktop/Shell/Test1/*
do
    echo inside loop
    filename=$(basename "$file")
    echo File -> $filename
done
```

---

Output:

```
Hello World
inside loop
demo.sh: line 8: $filename: ambiguous redirect
```

Comment: As a caution, be careful about specifying `#!/bin/sh`. That is *a lot* different than `bash`. Hence, the tag and the script are contradictory.

Comment: so what is the safest way to write ?

Comment: Could try: `echo *`,  `echo C:/*`, `echo /C:/*` in order to see how `*` will be expanded.

Comment: it showed me all the files in a single line basically i want is to get them in a variable one by one so as to compare or use them in other task

Comment: It's really up to you. There's not really a 'safest' way. There is a more portable way, using `sh`, but that limits your features, and depends on your execution target. If you're just running this locally, just use `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: if using `... file in /C:/Users/shubham.tomar/Desktop/Shell/Test1/*`  do result to `File -> *`,  I think `echo /C:/Users/shubham.tomar/Desktop/Shell/Test1/*` may not return what you expect.

Comment: It shows even without the for loop and displayed all the files inside shell folder in a single line what i want is to store their name in a variable and display them one by one in separate line

Comment: @ShubhamTomar : Apart from what has been discussed here already (the bug in your `echo` line and the odd #! line), your approach skips hidden files, and would cause an error message if there are no files in this directory.  Have a look at the shell options `nullglob` and `dotglob` in the bash man-page-

Answer (score 1):

Replace `echo File -> $filename` with `echo "File -> $filename"`

Comment: After the change output is this
File -> *

Comment: That means there are no files in your C:/Users/shubham.tomar/Desktop/Shell/Test1 directory.

Comment: doing a echo * in the same location gives me all the files in a single line and one more way i found echo ${file##*/} in place of " echo "File -> $filename" " give me all the files in a single line which ensures there are files. I want to fetch contents of Test1 folder which has some jar files

Comment: Because `echo ${file##*/}` results in `echo *`, which prints all files in the current directory. Try `echo "${file##*/}"` (with quotes). What does that print?